# ostrio:files package is working, but can’t access image

Tags: node.js, meteor, angular-meteor

I got the `ostrio:files` package working in my application, so my images are uploading to the server (as far as I know) and the DB has a reference to them, but I don’t know how to actually serve them up. For example, I uploaded an image this morning. The DB contains the original name, and the file path that it exists at now:

`assets/app/uploads/Images/twLXDmCTiqyGy4Yq7.jpg`

The problem is, when I put that into the url, it just returns my app’s homepage. I tried changing the upload directory to be `/images/` but still have the same issue. I can’t seem to find a clear answer in Meteor’s documentation on how to open up a path for images, aside from including them when you build the package, but that defeats the purpose of user-input.

I also have noticed that the `programs/web.browser/program.json` file in my application seems to control what is allowed to be visible, but ideally, I would just like to open up my /images directory to view any image (only direct paths, of course - I don’t want a directory listing). Is that a possibility?

Furthermore, I found the `config.public` configuration option in the [documentation](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Constructor#allow-collection-interaction-on-client-server), and set it to true, as well as setting the `storagePath` and `downloadRoute` paths. The paths I set are coming from the base of my server (using / for the start of the paths) but I still cannot seem to view any of the images that I upload - it just loads my default home page for my app

----EDIT----

Adding more detail for help in figuring this out.

I set up my FileCollection in my `/imports/api/images.js` file, like this:

`export const Images = new FilesCollection({`

Later on, in another file, I import that api and do the upload, using `Images.insert({` and then use the `upload.on('end', function` to get it uploaded. I'm guessing that is where I'm missing saving the file to my filesystem? Hopefully this helps and provides more detail for debugging. Also, when I do have a `FileCursor` object, I try the `link()` method and it just returns `link is not a function`.  I basically just followed the [Meteor Files GitHub Example](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files#insertsettings-autostart-client).

--- EDIT 2 ---

As pointed out by @Rolljee, I had other packages that were still in my project that I hadn't removed. They were interfering and causing this to not work.

Comment: Do you store the file on drive or using gridfs or collectionFS ? Also does it occur on local Dev or on deployment or both?

Comment: It occurs on both I guess... I'm using FileCollection with ostrio:files to store the images, but I can't seem to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store a new record in the FilesCollection collection, it automatically create the link() method you can use to get the path where it serve your file.

You should be able to get it like so:

```
const theUrl = MyFilesCollection.findOne(someId).link();
```

it is also possible to create the like yourself, it follow this simple naming convention:

```
link: `${Meteor.absoluteUrl() + file._downloadRoute}/${file._collectionName}/${file._id}/original/${file._id}.${file.extension}`,
```

Comment: Okay, so I looked into this more and even though I have a FileCursor, I still don't have the `link()` method. I tried the other thing you suggested, and it made a valid link, but when I go there, I just get `File Not Found :(`, but at least I'm getting something. So maybe it isn't actually uploading?

Comment: This is on my local, but I'm not getting any errors show up in the console when I upload an image.

Comment: using the .link() method doesn't do anything ? no error like .link() is not a function ?

Can you provide an exemple of how you upload the file ? 
And if possible the configuration you are using to create the collection ?

The file is not added to the collection until it has really created it in your folder. if you get the record, the file is suppose to be writted.

Comment: I added more detail to hopefully help in figuring this out.

Comment: Hi @Rolljee, do you have any ideas here? I have kept trying but am still running into issues... I would really appreciate more help if you can. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i was out for a while.
Did you set a 'storagePath' in the  export const Images = new FilesCollection({ ? You can try to set it then see if the file is uploaded in the folder you defined

Comment: Yes, it's set and I made sure that when I start my app, I'm not getting the error of '${this.storagePath({})} is not writeable'.

Comment: Could you make a repo of your project ? this should work. it's seem that maybe an other package is interfering with ostrio:files

Comment: I made a private repo - can you send me a PM here or give me your bitbucket username so I can add you to it?

Comment: Alright, i needed to create an account you can add me using username rolljee :)

Comment: Wow... I am so silly. I removed ostrio:files and another file manager and now it works! I feel so silly... thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Usually static assets are kept under public in your app structure, so public/images/picture.jpg is available as /images/picture.jpg in your HTML.

Unfortunately you can't save uploaded files to this directory (you probably know that), so another strategy is needed.

You don't say whether your problem is in development or production.

The sample code uses `<img src={{file.link}}<` - which means that the package will provide a url for you, based on the configuration. Does this not work? If you are formulating your own url, and you are going to deploy to mobile, the URL will need to be absolute, not relative, because of the way mobile apps run with a local web server for local assets.

This may not be a complete answer (yet), but if you can provide more information we can get there

Comment: I can't access my images on my dev environment or on production (at the /images/picture.jpg type of url) unless I put it in my public/images/picture.jpg before starting meteor. Also, when I do get an image using the ostrio:files thing (FileCollection), the image object I get back doesn't have any methods for `link` or `fileUrl` as suggested in the documentation. Maybe I'm doing something completely wrong and getting the wrong type of image object back?